# Query to list sales from a certain time period and difference in sales from previous time periods

Tags: sql-server

I normally build web tools with a MySQL db and my SQL skills aren't that advanced.   I've been thrown into building a report and it's over my head.

I've got a table where every 4 hours a job inserts the number of sales per product for the previous 4 hours.  One column of this table becomes the **date** and another column becomes a two digit number representing the **hour** (starting at midnight, the 4 hour intervals would be:
00,04,08,12,16,20).

The table looks like:

```
Item Color  Size    Hour    Date           Sales
ABC Yellow  S       00      2011-09-10      432
DEF Red     M       00      2011-09-10      1324
GHI Blue    L       00      2011-09-10      567
JKL Tan     XL      00      2011-09-10      967
MNO Green   S       00      2011-09-10      457
ABC Yellow  L       04      2011-09-10      852
```

I have to create a report where someone can list all sales for an upload period (say they pick the '08' upload for all sales between 4:00am and 7:59am.  That part is easy but I also need to add in the % difference between the previous 4, 8 & 12 hour periods.

For example (and only looking at product 'ABC' from above):  On the report page someone calls for a 2011-09-10 report for the Midnight ('04') report which would be the report uploaded at 4:00am for the sales between 12:00am and 03:59am:

```
**8:00pm - 11:59am Report**
Item  Color   Size  Date        Sales   4_hour_diff  8_hour_diff 12_hour_diff
ABC   Yellow  S     2011-09-10  852     1.9723       ---         ---
```

(the 4 hour difference being the sales were almost 200% higher than the previous 4 hour period - the "00" or 08:00pm to 11:59am time period earlier in the morning.

I know I can use logic on the application server side (ColdFusion in this case) to deal with the hour column going below 00 (date changing by -1).  I think what I need here is a sub-query for each "diff" field where each sub-query would find the sales from a previous time period and divided those by the sales of the main select.

I understand the concept of a sub-query but I've never had to write one (if that's what I should be trying to do here).  Plus, I've never had to us MS Sequel before.  Thanks for any help or tips in advance - much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this script:

```
use tempdb
GO

declare @date0 date, @date1 date, @date2 date, @date3 date
declare @hour0 int, @hour1 int, @hour2 int, @hour3 int

set @date0='20110910'
set @hour0=4


create table #tblSales(Item varchar(5), Color varchar(20),  Size varchar(2), [Hour] tinyint,  [Date] date, Sales int)

insert into #tblSales (Item, Color, Size, [Hour],  [Date], Sales) values ('ABC', 'Yellow',  'S',0, '20110910', 432)
insert into #tblSales (Item, Color, Size, [Hour],  [Date], Sales) values ('DEF', 'Red',     'M',0, '20110910',1324)
insert into #tblSales (Item, Color, Size, [Hour],  [Date], Sales) values ('GHI', 'Blue',    'L',0,  '20110910',567)
insert into #tblSales (Item, Color, Size, [Hour],  [Date], Sales) values ('JKL', 'Tan',     'XL',0, '20110910',967)
insert into #tblSales (Item, Color, Size, [Hour],  [Date], Sales) values ('MNO', 'Green',   'S',0,  '20110910',457)
insert into #tblSales (Item, Color, Size, [Hour],  [Date], Sales) values ('ABC', 'Yellow',  'L',4,  '20110910',852)
insert into #tblSales (Item, Color, Size, [Hour],  [Date], Sales) values ('ABC', 'Yellow',  'L',8,  '20110909',1852)

--this part can be done in WHILE
set @hour1=@hour0-4
set @date1=@date0
if @hour1<0
    begin
        set @hour1=12
        set @date1=DATEADD(dd,-1,@date0)
    end

set @hour2=@hour1-4
set @date2=@date1
if @hour2<0
    begin
        set @hour2=12
        set @date2=DATEADD(dd,-1,@date1)
    end

set @hour3=@hour2-4
set @date3=@date2
if @hour1<0
    begin
        set @hour3=12
        set @date3=DATEADD(dd,-1,@date2)
    end


select t0.Item, t0.Color, t0.Size, t0.Sales,
        cast(t0.Sales as float)/cast(t1.Sales as float)  '4-hour diff',
        cast(t0.Sales as float)/cast(t2.Sales as float)  '8-hour diff',
        cast(t0.Sales as float)/cast(t3.Sales as float)  '12-hour diff'
from #tblSales t0
     LEFT JOIN (select Item, Color, Sales from #tblSales where [Date]=@date1  AND [Hour]=@hour1) t1 on t0.Item=t1.Item and t0.Color=t1.Color
     LEFT JOIN (select Item, Color, Sales from #tblSales where [Date]=@date2  AND [Hour]=@hour2) t2 on t0.Item=t2.Item and t0.Color=t2.Color
     LEFT JOIN (select Item, Color, Sales from #tblSales where [Date]=@date3  AND [Hour]=@hour3) t3 on t0.Item=t3.Item and t0.Color=t3.Color
where t0.[Date]=@date0
      AND t0.[Hour]=@hour0


drop table #tblSales
```